# Rolle's theorem for functions of several variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

It's about creating an analogous of rollers theorem. Check this out :

[Prove an analog of Rolle's theorem for several variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428653/prove-an-analog-of-rolles-theorem-for-several-variables)

Check the answer which is accepted. I couldn't get how did we conclude that if there exists a point where $f'(x)=0$ then there should exist $x_1<x_0<x_2$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$

Comment: What do you mean by $x_1<x_0<x_2?$ Is not $f$ supposed to be a function on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n?$

Comment: Take them as points in $R^2$

Comment: What does it mean for points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the relation $<?$ With respect to what order? On the other hand, I don't see what you say in the answer.